# FormsAuthentication not working. IsAuthenticated always return False

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, httpcontext, httpcookie

I am developing website by using ASP.net and I want to implement formbased authentication. 
In web.config I use this

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

In login button click I use this.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;
                string cookieString;
                HttpCookie cookie;

                ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtiLoginEmail.Value, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), chbRememberMe.Checked, null);
                cookieString = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieString);


                if (chbRememberMe.Checked)
                {
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                    cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                string strRedirect = "post.aspx";
                Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
```

I have a page called post.aspx . I want this page to be acess only for authenticated users. So at the page load event of post.aspx page I use this code to check it

```
  bool isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

But above code always return false. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(/*UserHere*/ ,false);
```